# How to search for a file in a FAT12 system in Assembly

Tags: assembly, operating-system

Currently, I've been following the BrokenThorn Series on OS Dev, and I've run into a bit of a problem. Right now, as a part of my journey through the tutorial, I'm currently coding the part that loads in a second stage bootloader, but unfortunately, the code crashes. Here is the portion of the code that I think is troublesome:

Code:

```
;browse root directory for binary image
     mov     ax, WORD [bpbRootEntries]; load loop counter, bpbRootEntries is the number of entries in the FAT table
     mov     di, 0x0000 ; because rep cmpsb compares the string in es:di to ds:si, and es holds 0x7e00 (the location of the FAT Table), I decided to set di to 0x0000
     mov     cx, 0x000B; eleven character name           
     lea     si, [ImageName] ;set si to the memory location of ImageName so ds:si points to ImageName          
 .LOOP:     
 rep  cmpsb     
      jz     LOAD_FAT
      add     di, 32                            ; queue next directory entry
      dec ax
      cmp ax, 0x0
 jne .LOOP

 jmp     FAILURE
```

This portion of code looks for the file in the FAT table. However, it is not able to find it, and so crashes.
In this code, ImageName is a variable with the value "KRNLDR SYS" in it. In my floppy drive, I have a file called "KRNLDR SYS" in my floppy drive (with the spaces, not "KRNLDR.SYS"). It would be a great help if anyone could offer any advice.

Note: I'm currently runnning a 64-bit Windows 7 PC

**UPDATE**

After all the helpful comments, I have updated the code:

```
mov     ax, WORD [bpbRootEntries]             ; load loop counter
 mov     di, 0x0000                            ; locate first root entry
 mov     cx, 0x000B                            ; eleven character name               
 lea     si, [ImageName]                         ; image name to find            
 .LOOP:
      push di
      push si
      repe  cmpsb   
      pop di
      pop si
      jz     LOAD_FAT

      add     di, 32                            ; queue next directory entry

      dec ax
      or ax, ax
      jne .LOOP

      jmp     FAILURE
```

Unfortunately, the OS is still not able to find the file.

**UPDATE 2**

Here is the code I've used to load the Root Directory Table:

```
     LOAD_ROOT:

 ; compute size of root directory and store in "cx"

      xor si, si

      mov     ax, 0x0020                           ; 32 byte directory entry
      mul     WORD [bpbRootEntries]                ; total size of directory
      div     WORD [bpbBytesPerSector]             ; sectors used by directory
      xchg    ax, cx

 ; compute location of root directory and store in "ax"

      mov     al, BYTE [bpbNumberOfFATs]            ; number of FATs
      mul     WORD [bpbSectorsPerFAT]               ; sectors used by FATs
      add     ax, WORD [bpbReservedSectors]         ; adjust for bootsector
      mov     WORD [datasector], ax                 ; base of root directory
      add     WORD [datasector], cx

 ; read root directory into memory (7C00:0200)

     mov   dx, 0x7e00
     mov   es, dx
     mov     bx, 0x0                             ; copy root dir above bootcode
     call    ReadSectors
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you certain that the filesystem on your floppy is actually FAT12, and that the file is really named "KRNLDR SYS"?

Comment: So, I named the file KRNLDR.SYS in windows. In the bootloader, I'm searching for KRNLDR SYS (with 2 spaces). But still, the code is not able to find the file. I'm using VFD to create a virtual floppy drive and format it. I'm using RawWrite to right the bootloader to sector 0, and using a copy command in windows to load KRNLDR to the floppy. Is there a problem with this setup?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The `REP` on the `CMPSB` will repeat the `CMPSB` `CX` times regardless and `ZF` will be set to the result of the LAST comparison made.

- You need a `REPE` here

Even with a `REPE`, `REPE CMPSB` will modify both `DI` and `SI` so that they will each point to the byte AFTER the last byte compared (Let's assume that `DF` is set for UP) Hence adding 32 to `DI` **CERTAINLY** won't point to the next FAT entry.

- You need to `PUSH` both `DI` and `SI` before the `REPE CMPSB` and `POP` them back immediately after (which won't affect the `FLAGS`)

That way, neither `DI` nor `SI` appears to be changed and the adding of 32 is valid.

By way of finesse, `OR AX,AX` will set `ZF` to the same as `CMP AX,0x0` but is a smaller, faster instruction.

Comment: As you have suggested, I have corrected my code. The new version is posted in the original question as an update. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, so close! And yes - saw you transfer the amendment. Good idea. Now you need to understand stacks. It's a LIFO buffer - Last-In First Out. Since you `PUSH` `DI` and `SI` in that order, then you need to `POP` in reverse order, so that the original `SI` is restored to `SI` etc. As it stands, the original `SI` and `DI` will be swapped - and hence your matching won't be as you expect it...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I was not aware of this, and I have corrected that problem in my code. However, the file is still not being found. I think the problem lies in the way I set up my virtual floppy. I have described my setup in a comment on my original question. Is it possible for you to take a look at it?

Comment: Could you show the way you've defined `IMAGENAME` and the FAT table and how you've made sure that `ES:0` points to the base of the FAT table.

Comment: This is the code I've used to define ImageName: `ImageName db "KRNLDR  SYS"` (two spaces). Above, I've attached the code Ive used to load the FAT table

Comment: Hmm... now without asking what `READSECTORS` does (actually how it does what it seems to suggest...) mu attention was drawn to the comment `; read root directory into memory (7C00:0200)` yet you are loading `ES` through `DX` with `7e00`. Problem is that a memory segment is 16 bytes long. The ABSOLUTE address is (segment * 16)+offset so the location 7c00:0200 is actually 7c200 absolute, not 7e000. Therefore you need to know exactly where the data is being read TO and set your registers accordingly.

Comment: I changed the code so that `es` holds the quantity `0x07c0`, and bx (which is the offset) holds `0x200`. Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've fixed it (sort of). I used a Hex editor called WinHex, and located the location of file in memory, and hardcoded it into the program. its temporary, but it will be sufficient until I can start programming in C for my kernel, which I think will be slightly simpler than Assembly. Thanks for all your help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same as you but on Linux (Brokenthorn OS tutorial) with Bochs.
I create a floppy-image and use that with Bochs.
For me the code that is in Demo1.zip (Stage2) works.
It reads the second stage loader from Fat12.
However in the beginning it didn't work because when I copied the bootsector to the floppy-image, the floppy-image got truncated.
Note that I only changed the text to print out in Stage2.asm .

https://sites.google.com/site/forthoperatingsystem/